# Why can't I use DateFormatter property generateCalendarDates?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am working on a piece of code that is manipulating dates. Instances of the class `DateFormatter` have a property on them called `generateCalendarDates`. This is a boolean I believe is used to create a date based on the current calendar. However when I attempt to assign or inspect this property in Xcode I receive a description of the property from my code completion.

[image]

It actually tells me not to use this property. I was wondering why this is. Because I was actually thinking about using it.

Comment: NSCalendarDate is no longer supported. Just don't use it. Why would you need it?

Comment: Oh I see. I would have thought it just wouldn't appear as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generatesCalendarDates` property tells `NSDateFormatter` to create instances of `NSCalendarDate` instead of `NSDate` when it parses a date.

It's not available to you in Swift because `NSCalendarDate` is deprecated, and most deprecated APIs are not available in Swift.

So what was `NSCalendarDate`? It was a subclass of `NSDate` that added a `timeZone` property and had methods to perform calculations using the Gregorian calendar.

Why was it deprecated? Because Apple introduced the `NSCalendar` class in Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger). You can use instances of `NSCalendar` to perform calculations using several different calendars, including the Gregorian. `NSCalendar` has its own `timeZone` property, where it makes sense; `NSDate` objects are always timezone-independent.

`DateFormatter` parses (and formats) dates using its `calendar` property. By default, that `calendar` property is set to `Calendar.current`, which is the system calendar. The user can choose the system calendar in Settings > General > Language & Region > Calendar.

You can set the `calendar` property explicitly to Gregorian if you want: `dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`. But I wouldn't recommend it. If the user has chosen a different calendar, are you sure you want to force the use of Gregorian?